# How to create more space for OS X in VirtualBox?

Tags: macos, mac, disk-space

I follow this youtube tutorial: [How to Create ISO File to install Mac OS X on VMware and VirtualBox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZyUWMJgDI8). It works perfectly until this step:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the help center (OS X running on VirtualBox Windows host).

Answer (score 1):

Try to allocate more disk space in your VirtualBox configuration (before booting the machine).

In VirtualBox:

1. Click on your machine
2. Configuration
3. Storage tab (on the left)
4. Click on your disk
5. Click on the button in the top right (check fig. 1)
6. Create new disk (it seems that the data will be moved from the disk to another)

Fig. 1 :
[image]